# I need to calculate the data frame columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have an employee data_frame for every hundred of his income there will be an increment amount, I do have an issue how to calculate the data frame column and extending the columns

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['Bob', 'Jane', 'Alice'], 
                   'increment': [2, 6, 4],
                   'income' : [100, 400, 300]})

   user  increment  income
0    Bob           2     100
1   Jane           6     400
2  Alice           4     300
```

I need to know how to calculate the above data frame  and final result should be like this in the below income max_limit is 5000

```
     user  increment  income
0    Bob        2       100
     Bob        4       200
     Bob        6       300
     Bob        8       400
    Jane        6       400
    Jane       12       800
    Jane       18       1200
    Jane       24       1600
    Alice       4       300 
    Alice       8       600
    Alice       12      900
    Alice       16      1200
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please fix the question format, split text from code and make it easy to understand.

Comment: Why does Bob have an increment of 6 and an income of 300, while Jane has an increment of 6 and an income of 400? I can't see any pattern to this data.

Comment: @KWx each employee has it's  own income and different increment based on there designation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pandas.Index.repeat` and then `groupby.agg`:

```
limit = 1000 # Changed from 5,000 to 1,000 for short example
new_df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(limit / df['income'])]
new_df.update(new_df.groupby('user').agg({'income': 'cumsum', 'increment': 'cumsum'}))
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
   income  increment   user
0     100          2    Bob
0     200          4    Bob
0     300          6    Bob
0     400          8    Bob
0     500         10    Bob
0     600         12    Bob
0     700         14    Bob
0     800         16    Bob
0     900         18    Bob
0    1000         20    Bob
1     400          6   Jane
1     800         12   Jane
2     300          4  Alice
2     600          8  Alice
2     900         12  Alice
```